# How can I read a multiline text file (separator newline) as a header for a different csv data file?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have separate header and body files. The body file is a csv file with a custom delimiter. The header file is a multiline file with each column name in one line. I would like to find out how to read the header file.

tried using multiline option and newline as separator

```
df = spark.read.format('text') \
    .options(header='true', delimiter='\n', multiLine='true') \
    .load("filenamewithpath")
```

I see 2nd row of df as the second row of the input file. I was expecting all columns to be in 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Read header file separately as :-

```
val head = spark.read.text("****/head.txt")
```

Read headers and collect it as an Array.

```
val headers = head.as[String].collect
```

Read the csv file and then apply the header to the DataFrame as below:-

```
data.toDF(headers:_*)
```